# Python Webdriver Unable to locate the xpath in facebook for Liked button in pages

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, xpath, webdriver

[Need xpath of "Liked" button(Image attached here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzxcb.png)

I tried these but getting error.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[contains(text(), 'Liked'").click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[contains(text(), 'Liked'").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: share the html for Liked button. FB restricted in my office :(

Comment: Html shared here. @ShoaibAkhtar https://pastebin.com/BbsqZi91

Comment: Why do you need to interact with a Like button using selenium in the first place? I don’t see what that would be useful for, except for creating fake likes.

Comment: Not for creating fake likes. I'm just writing script for **unliking** pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//button[contains(text(), 'Liked')]").click()

driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//button[contains(text(), 'Liked')]").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

You missed brackets.please try with above xpath.

You can also try official facebbok api for data collection

Comment: Getting error.  **selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression ".//button[contains(text(), 'Liked')" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.**